# How to get number of elements in json using jq

Tags: json, count, jq

I'd like to get the count of elements in an json array using jq (without the elements with "name": "current" in the snapshots array).

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "description": "You are here!",
      "name": "current",
      "digest": "ccc",
      "running": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "You are here!",
      "name": "snap1",
      "digest": "ddd",
      "running": 1
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "test2",
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "digest": "bbb",
      "description": "You are here!",
      "name": "current",
      "running": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "You are here!",
      "name": "snap1",
      "digest": "aaa",
      "running": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "You are here!",
      "name": "snap2",
      "digest": "abc",
      "running": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the result I'm looking for (excluding the entries with "name: "current" in the snapshots array):

```
test1: 1
test2: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to combine string interpolation by writing the filter inside the `".."`

```
jq --raw-output 
  '"\(.name): \( .snapshots | map(select(.name != "current")) | length )"'
```

demo - [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/jjhspVblxVM)

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to define a count function and use that. Using `reduce` can make it a little quicker too for larger inputs.

```
def count(f): reduce (.[] | f) as $i (0; if $i then . + 1 end);
"\(.name): \(.snapshots | count(.name != "current"))"
```

Answer (score 0):

... or use the generic stream-oriented `count/1` function:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $_ (0; .+1);

"\(.name): \(count(.snapshots[] | select(.name != "current")))"
```